# Mithril redraw only 1 module

Tags: mithril.js

If I have like 10 `m.module` on my page, can I call `m.startComputation`, `m.endComputation`, `m.redraw` or `m.request` for only one of those modules?

It looks like any of these will redraw all of my modules.

I know only `module 1` will be affected by some piece of code, I only want mithril to redraw that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, there's no simple support for multi-tenancy (i.e. running multiple modules independently of each other).

The workaround would involve using subtree directives to prevent redraws on other modules, e.g.

```
//helpers
var target
function tenant(id, module) {
  return {
    controller: module.controller,
    view: function(ctrl) {
      return target == id ? module.view(ctrl) : {subtree: "retain"}
    }
  }
}
function local(id, callback) {
  return function(e) {
    target = id
    callback.call(this, e)
  }
}

//a module
var MyModule = {
  controller: function() {
    this.doStuff = function() {alert(1)}
  },
  view: function() {
    return m("button[type=button]", {
      onclick: local("MyModule", ctrl.doStuff)
    }, "redraw only MyModule")
  }
}

//init
m.module(element, tenant("MyModule", MyModule))
```

You could probably also use something like [this](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril-blog/when-css-lets-you-down.html) or [this](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril-blog/extending-the-view-language.html) to automate decorating of event handlers w/ `local`

Comment: Here is the link for gist with component support : https://gist.github.com/dhinesh03/4408820e78d14738f979

Answer (score 1):

Need multi-tenancy support for components ? Here is my [gist link](https://gist.github.com/dhinesh03/4408820e78d14738f979)

```
var z = (function (){
  //helpers
  var cache = {};
  var target;
  var type = {}.toString;
  var tenant=function(componentName, component) {     
      return {
        controller: component.controller,
        view: function(ctrl) {
          var args=[];
          if (arguments.length > 1) args = args.concat([].slice.call(arguments, 1))
          if((type.call(target) === '[object Array]' &&  target.indexOf(componentName) > -1) ||  target === componentName ||  target === "all")
            return component.view.apply(component, args.length ? [ctrl].concat(args) : [ctrl])
          else
            return {subtree: "retain"}
        }
      }
  }
  return {      
    withTarget:function(components, callback) {
      return function(e) {
        target = components;
        callback.call(this, e)
      }
    },    
    component:function(componentName,component){
      //target = componentName;
      var args=[];
      if (arguments.length > 2) args = args.concat([].slice.call(arguments, 2))
      return m.component.apply(undefined,[tenant(componentName,component)].concat(args));
    },  
    setTarget:function(targets){
      target = targets;
    },
    bindOnce:function(componentName,viewName,view) {
      if(cache[componentName] === undefined) {
        cache[componentName] = {};
      }
      if (cache[componentName][viewName] === undefined) {
          cache[componentName][viewName] = true
          return view()
      }
      else return {subtree: "retain"}
    },
    removeCache:function(componentName){
      delete cache[componentName]
    }
  }
})();
```